# Room object in Revit files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I followed the instruction in the link below to extract Room objects from Revit models:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces

I made the changes as instructed and tested the sample Revit file (rac_basic_sample_project.rvt). But, still I don't see the rooms or the viewables (phases). Below is fhe request I post. Am I missing anything?

```
{
  "input": {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YzQ4ZDUxNDNhMDRiNDAxNmI3ODYxY2NlMzQ2ZDkyNjdfZmFjaWxpdHlfOTUvZWIyYzMzNDgtNDAxYS00ZjQ3LTgwM2EtMjM1OGYwYmI0YjY2LnJ2dA"
  },
  "output": {
    "destination": {
      "region": "us"
    },
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": [
          "3d"
        ],
        "advanced": {
          "generateMasterViews": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the feature and I can see the room data:

[image]

The JSON payload seems ok, so try checking the following things:

- Make sure you use the `x-ads-force` header (explained in the blog post you linked to); if you had already processed your Revit model before, triggering a new Model Derivative job would not do anything unless you force the translation
- Try using another design (and from a newer version of Revit if possible); in my screenshot I'm using one of the [official samples for Revit 2020](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html), although I remember being able to get the room data from older samples as well
- The room data is only available in certain "viewables" so make sure you're looking at the right one; for my sample project, for example, the room data is not available in the "{3D}" viewable but it is available in the "Working Drawings" viewable

Comment: As for the 2nd item, I tried sample file from both the 2020 and 2021 versions.

As for the 3rd item, should I load viewables seperately, or they will automatically appear in the model browser?

Comment: I tried new files, same result, no room or viewable

Comment: Other, non-default viewables will *not* appear in the Model Browser. In your code you probably have something like `viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry());`, right? You'll want to replace that with `viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().findByGuid(guid));`, providing the GUID of one of the viewables like "Working Drawings".

Comment: Because again, the default viewable ("{3D}" in case of the official Revit sample project) does *not* contain the room data.

Comment: Also, consider using the [Visual Studio Code extension for Forge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) - you can explore your Forge data and derivatives there more easily.