# Rooms don't fetch in the document browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I could not find rooms/spaces in the document browser of Autodesk platform services simple viewer. I looked over some documentation related to this saying that we should generate master view of the model while translating it to SVF. Anyone has any idea how can we make rooms visible in the document browser?

Answer (score 0):

To generate master views for your models in APS, you can have a look at this APS blog post that explains how users can achieve this: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces

You can also have a look at a similar question that could give you an idea of how to generate room objects from Revit models: [Room object in Revit files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272031/room-object-in-revit-files)